# Creating a calendar to-do list in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am working on an Excel file for a co-worker. She is trying to create a spreadsheet where a task list can auto-add to a visual calendar on another tab. The Calendar has the visual representation of a desktop calendar, with the month and date at the top of the spreadsheet, followed by blocks with "1", "2", etc. for the days of the month.

TAB A

- Task column
- Due Date column

TAB B (Calendar)

- Month
- Day
- Calendar Day

She is wanting to have the task list feed into the calendar, creating a task on each day for which it's due.

[task list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJIBE.png)

However, I've run into a problem trying to feed the task list into each date square. I keep getting errors, because I know that the list being created with a VLOOKUP.

[calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4qCF.png)

Any thoughts or assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: What OS and version is she using?

Comment: If Windows and Office 365, try using `FILTER()` to get all tasks for a day and `TEXTJOIN()` to put them together.

Comment: I'm having trouble even getting the tasks for a specific day to even feed into the calendar on the proper day at this moment.

Comment: If `FILTER()` is available, use it instead of `VLOOKUP()`, which will only get you the first matching item. Then nest `FILTER()` inside of `TEXTJOIN()`.

Answer (score 0):

FILTER() function worked to apply one list to the calendar date squares.

[final calendar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVTwn.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).